# Is SuperLearning actually different to stacking,or are they essentially the same thing?

Tags: data-mining, ensemble-modeling

Articles which use the terms 'stacking' and 'Super Learner' often seem to use the terms interchangeably. Is the Super Learner algorithm a specific form of the more generic stacking concept, or is Super Learner essentially the same thing, and at some stage one of these terms is likely to become redundant?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So Ensemble Learning is essentially using multiple learning algorithms and providing the best predictive performance considering all of them. [This](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~ledell/docs/dlab_ensembles.pdf) gives a better detailed description. Now, Ensemble Learning can be broadly divided into multiple types like

- Boosting
- Bagging
- Stacking / Super Learning

Stacking contains a bunch of algorithms along with a learner to ensemble a group of base learners. Going deeper, the term [Stacking](http://statistics.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/tech-reports/367.pdf) was used way before Super Learning. Later, when the algorithm was actually developed theoretically and made popular in 2007, it was given the name 'Super Learner'.

Comment: Welcome to the site. That is a really good first answer :)